# Is possible to decorate a f2py-compiled function with numba.jit?

Tags: python, numpy, numba, f2py

Say I have this function that works on 1-d arrays:

```
def opfunc(a, b):
    if len(a.shape) != 1 and len(b.shape) != 1:
        raise ValueError('opfunc: both inputs must be 1-d arrays.')
    return 2 * b + 2 * (a[0] - a[-1])
```

and I want to use it repeatedly in loops or nested loops like this

```
nx1, nx2, nx3 = a.shape
c = np.zeros(a.shape)
for ix1 in range(nx1):
    for ix2 in range(nx2):
        avec = a[ix1, ix2, :]
        bvec = b[ix1, ix2, :]
        cvec = opfunc(avec, bvec)
            c[ix1, ix2, :] = cvec
```

I can speed this up by putting these statements in a function and decorating it and `opfunc` with `numba.jit`:

```
@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def opfunc(a, b):
    if len(a.shape) != 1 and len(b.shape) != 1:
        raise ValueError('opfunc: both inputs must be 1-d arrays.')
    return 2 * b + 2 * (a[0] - a[-1])

@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def opfunc1(a, b):
    nx1, nx2, nx3 = a.shape
    c = np.zeros(a.shape)
    for ix1 in range(nx1):
        for ix2 in range(nx2):
            avec = a[ix1, ix2, :]
            bvec = b[ix1, ix2, :]
            cvec = opfunc(avec, bvec)
            c[ix1, ix2, :] = cvec
    return c
```

Definite speed-up here.

Is it possible to do a similar thing if `opfunc` is written in Fortran

```
$ !cat fortran_test.f90

module test_fortran

  implicit none

contains

  subroutine opfunc(a, b, c)
    implicit none

    real (kind=8), dimension(6), intent(in) :: a, b
    real (kind=8), dimension(6), intent(out) :: c

    c = 2 * b + 2 !* (a(1) - a(ubound(a)))
  end subroutine opfunc

end module test_fortran
```

and has been imported into Python with f2py?

```
import fortran_test

opfuncx = fortran_test.test_fortran.opfunc

@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def opfunc1x(a, b):
    nx1, nx2, nx3 = a.shape
    c = np.zeros(a.shape)
    for ix1 in range(nx1):
        for ix2 in range(nx2):
            avec = a[ix1, ix2, :]
            bvec = b[ix1, ix2, :]
            cvec = opfuncx(avec, bvec)
            c[ix1, ix2, :] = cvec
    return c
```

As it is, I'm getting

```
TypingError: Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'opfuncx'
File "<ipython-input-48-c51d5b4fdad5>", line 13
```

when running the function.  I am guessing that it is because `opfuncx` has not been decorated with `numba.jit`.  Is it possible to do this?

Comment: You can't do this directly (I think) but you might be able to use `cffi` to call the Fortran functions from within Numba. It used to be documented (http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.15.1/interface_c.html); I think (but I'm not 100% sure) that it still works but the documentation has just dissappeared.

Comment: Actually, they just moved the documentation http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html#cffi